# Heap insert implementation via Dafny (with specifications)

Tags: insert, heap, dafny

I'm writing HeapInsert in Dafny but I can't prove the correctness of the code.

I tried writing it with this algorithm:
I'm using this algorithm:

```
heap_size++; 
int i = heap_size - 1; 
harr[i] = k; 

while (i != 0 && harr[parent(i)] <= harr[i]) 
{ 
   swap(&harr[i], &harr[parent(i)]); 
   i = parent(i); 
}
```

but I have no idea what is the invariant of the loop, and its pretty hard to prove it.

I need to write the HeapInsert in dafny with specifications and proof.

Comment: can you clarify the question by showing us what you have so far in Dafny? for example, how are you encoding `parent`? what properties of the code do you want to prove?

Comment: Thank you for the response,
I encoded parent like this:
method Parent(i: nat) returns (k: nat) { return (i-1)/2; }

Comment: I need to prove everything from the beginning till the end,
this is the given specification: 
method HeapInsert(a: array<int>, heapsize: nat, x: int)
 requires heapsize < a.Length
 requires hp(a[..], heapsize)
 ensures hp(a[..], heapsize+1)
 ensures multiset(a[..heapsize+1]) == multiset(old(a[..heapsize])+[x])
 modifies a

Comment: can you please edit the question to include the specification and the code you have so far? for example, `&` is not valid Dafny, so the code you have in the question is more like pseudo-C, rather than Dafny. this makes it difficult to help you.